# DialogFlow CX inline system functions not working in text fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I would like to generate dynamic text without the need to create webhooks whenever possible. I understand that the only way to create dynamic text is by either creating different routes depending on parameters or by [using inline system functions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-functions) like `$sys.func.ADD(1, 2)` within text fulfillments.

But inline system functions like `$sys.func.ADD(1, 2)` do not work for me if used in text fulfillments. System functions just don't get executed for me. I.e. instead of uttering "3" my bot just utters "$sys.func.ADD(1, 2)" as a result of a test fulfillemnt. What am I doing wrong here? Does anybody have an example for using inline system functions in text fulfillment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you need to [check the result of system functions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-functions#results) in order to identify the error that occurred.

For the system function **$sys.func.ADD**, when using it as a text response in your fulfillment, you need to convert it to type **`STRING`** to be embedded in text since the output of this system function returns a type **`DOUBLE`**.

You can convert the output of the **$sys.func.ADD** function to **`STRING`** by creating a nested function in your text response and utilizing the [**$sys.func.TO_TEXT**](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-functions#func-totext) which converts a value of other types to string.

Here’s an example for reference:
[image: Result]

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Solves my issue 100%. Thanks a lot!!!